# Javascript scroll to top script ammendment

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrolltop

I am trying to alter this script so that when the topcontrol div element is not visible (opacity is 0) it  is not clickable, because at the moment even when the opacity of the topcontrol div is 0, it can still be clicked (and the function to move to the top can still be called) - also if you hover over where the div is, it shows the title (I was going to get rid of the title though, so just need to  make sure clicking on it does nothing). Also, I cannot seem to change the css cursor property, at the moment I try to change it along with the opacity value when the visibility property is set, but it doesn't seem to work, it just stays as what it is initially set as.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated as my javascript knowledge is pretty pants.

```
//** jQuery Scroll to Top Control script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library:     http://www.dynamicdrive.com.
//** Available/ usage terms at http://www.dynamicdrive.com (March 30th, 09')
//** v1.1 (April 7th, 09'):
//** 1) Adds ability to scroll to an absolute position (from top of page) or specific element on the page instead.
//** 2) Fixes scroll animation not working in Opera. 


var scrolltotop={
//startline: Integer. Number of pixels from top of doc scrollbar is scrolled before showing control
//scrollto: Keyword (Integer, or "Scroll_to_Element_ID"). How far to scroll document up when control is clicked on (0=top).
setting: {startline:500, scrollto: 0, scrollduration:600, fadeduration:[600, 400]},
controlHTML: '<div class="scroll-button"></div>', //HTML for control, which is auto wrapped in DIV w/ ID="topcontrol"
controlattrs: {offsetx:20, offsety:100}, //offset of control relative to right/ top of window corner
anchorkeyword: '#top', //Enter href value of HTML anchors on the page that should also act as "Scroll Up" links

state: {isvisible:false, shouldvisible:false},

scrollup:function(){
    if (!this.cssfixedsupport) //if control is positioned using JavaScript
        this.$control.css({cursor:'default', opacity:0}) //hide control immediately after clicking it
    var dest=isNaN(this.setting.scrollto)? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto)
    if (typeof dest=="string" && jQuery('#'+dest).length==1) //check element set by string exists
        dest=jQuery('#'+dest).offset().top
    else
        dest=0
    this.$body.animate({scrollTop: dest}, this.setting.scrollduration);
},

keepfixed:function(){
    var $window=jQuery(window)
    var controlx=$window.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - this.$control.width()  - this.controlattrs.offsetx
    var controly=$window.scrollTop() + $window.height() -  this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety
    this.$control.css({left:controlx+'px', top:controly+'px'})
},

togglecontrol:function(){
    var scrolltop=jQuery(window).scrollTop()
    if (!this.cssfixedsupport)
        this.keepfixed()
    this.state.shouldvisible=(scrolltop>=this.setting.startline)? true : false
    if (this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible){
        this.$control.stop().animate({cursor:'pointer', opacity:1}, this.setting.fadeduration[0])
        this.state.isvisible=true
    }
    else if (this.state.shouldvisible==false && this.state.isvisible){
        this.$control.stop().animate({cursor:'default', opacity:0}, this.setting.fadeduration[1])
        this.state.isvisible=false
    }
},

init:function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var mainobj=scrolltotop
        var iebrws=document.all
        mainobj.cssfixedsupport=!iebrws || iebrws && document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //not IE or IE7+ browsers in standards mode
        mainobj.$body=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body')
        mainobj.$control=$('<div   id="topcontrol">'+mainobj.controlHTML+'</div>')
            .css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', top:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'default'})
            .attr({title:'Scroll Up'})
            .click(function(){mainobj.scrollup(); return false})
            .appendTo('body')
        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && mainobj.$control.text()!='') //loose check for IE6 and below, plus whether control contains any text
            mainobj.$control.css({width:mainobj.$control.width()})    //IE6- seems to require an explicit width on a DIV containing text
        mainobj.togglecontrol()
        $('a[href="' + mainobj.anchorkeyword +'"]').click(function(){
            mainobj.scrollup()
            return false
        })
        $(window).bind('scroll resize', function(e){
            mainobj.togglecontrol()
        })
    })
}
```

The script can be seen in action here - jakobfolin.com/portfolio.html 
    }

```
scrolltotop.init()
```

Comment: I took a look on your page, but to be honest I have no idea what div you are speaking about and what behavior I am seeing that would prompt me to know what div you speak of :-). I am "guessing" that the nav is what you mean. Can you be a bit more specific. ie.. "when I scroll and the div that is ____ does ____, I don't want to be able click on it" etc..

Comment: Which browser you're testing on? In IEs setting `opacity: 0` keeps mouseevents alive. Instead you can use `background+color: transparent`, though this won't prevent mouseevents in other browsers, in which (& IE11) you can create an unresponsive element using `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: Why not just use `display:none` ? with the actions `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` ?

Comment: im testing it in chrome and firefox at the moment, was going to get round to ie though so will try that property

Comment: using the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() fixed everything.